# How to get the postion of the lid

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, terminal, cocoa

I am trying to figure out what the position of the lid is. Whether it is open or closed. Is there a terminal command or a cocoa code snippet for this?

I've already tried `pmset -g` but i can only get the sleep modes and the lidwake status.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't have a macbook by my side, is maybe

```
ioreg -r -k AppleClamshellState -d 4 | grep AppleClamshellState  | head -1
```

still working ?

Comment: You are my hero, works perfectly fine. Thank you very much :)